# CSS padding issue using box-sizing:border-box in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, padding, border-box

I'm having a weird issue in Firefox, it looks likes the debug console is lying to me or I'm missing something.

Here is the CSS for the body tag :

```
html, body {
    width: 100%; 
}

body {
    padding: 5% 10% 0 10%; 
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: 300; 
    color: #2b2b2b; 
    margin: auto; 
    max-width: 1200px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I'm using the property "box-sizing" so the max-width is supposed to be 1200px with the padding inside. As the debug console is saying (at the bottom right), the width of the content area is supposed to be 898px but if I measure it, here is what I really get :

[image: CSS padding issue using box-sizing:border-box in Firefox]

Am I mistaken about the box-sizing:border-box property ?

Thank you guys !

**EDIT :** I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VJA52/1/) with a simplified case.

Look at the image below, you'll find the html, the box model given by the inspector, the render and a red square I added on Photoshop (which is really 150x150px). I don't understand, the inspector is saying that the box is 150x150 but it's wrong...

[image: box-sizing and inspector issue on Firefox]

Comment: I may be wrong about this but I don't think you can set a max-width on the body tag as this is your view port and will always expand to the size of the screen.  Try adding a div inside the body tag and styling that

Comment: Thank you for your interesting answer, I made a quick test but the problem remains the same. It looks like doing it on the html element is ok (as [Chris Coyier is saying here](http://css-tricks.com/limit-html-width/)) so I guess it's also the case for the body tag.

Comment: Your fiddle shows the same size box for me in both Firefox and other browsers...

Comment: On Chrome 31.0.1650.63 the box is 150x150px for real, not on Firefox 26.0. Are you using the same versions ? I'm on Windows 8 and you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Windows 8 is zooming at 125% by default and Firefox is using this ratio as his default zoom level.

Then you have two choices :

1. Change the zoom level of Windows to 100% : **control pannel > appearance > display**
2. Set the Firefox's zoom ratio to 1.0 : type **about:config** in the adress bar of the browser, search for **layout.css.devPixelsPerPx** and set it to **1.0**

More informations about this here : https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/963759

Good to know that most of Windows 8's users are going to see your site zooming at 125% in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

#### Which version you are using... If you are using old version than try addking -moz-

```
{
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* for older webkit browsers */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;  /* for older mozilla browsers */
box-sizing: border-box;  /* for latest browsers */
}
```

Comment: As you can see in my question, I gave the css and I'm already using browser prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

because your `padding values` are calculated from the whole screen, not from `1200px`. As you resize the window(make it smaller), you will see that the paddings will adjust according the screen width value, not from `1200px`

Comment: The calculated padding values (151px) given by the debug console are ok for me, the problem is that it is not real. Take a look at the screenshot, the width of the content area is supposed to be 898px but it's not the case.